# JSX not visible in react native android mobile but visible in emulator

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jsx, custom-font

I have a weird bug where pricing is visible in emulator and works just fine but when checking on mobile, it does not show up although its there but just not showing. I have tried changing font color, adding if condition etc. but just does not work.

Also, on noticing and playing around with the bug, i have found that when number is big after decimal point, it does show up.(Screenshot Attached) but does not show up when it is smaller.

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amMwS.png)

[Mobile Screenshot price visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zsJ0.jpg)

[Mobile Screenshot price not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yayKM.jpg)

Function used to add comma to price.

```
export function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
```

Code used to preview total at the End.

```
return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Tab.Navigator>

                <Tab.Screen name="One-Time Cart" component={OneTimeCart} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Subscription Cart" component={SubscriptionCart} />

            </Tab.Navigator>

            <View style={styles.cartTotal}>
                <View style={styles.cartTotalSubView}>
                    <Text style={styles.cartAllText}>One Time Cart:</Text>
                    <Text style={[styles.price, styles.cartAllText]}>₹ {numberWithCommas(grandTotal[0])}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.cartTotalSubView}>
                    <Text style={styles.cartAllText}>SubScription Cart:</Text>
                    <Text style={[styles.price, styles.cartAllText]}>₹ {numberWithCommas(grandTotal[1])}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.cartTotalSubView}>
                    <Text style={styles.cartAllText}>Total:</Text>
                    <Text style={[styles.price, styles.cartAllText]}>₹ {numberWithCommas(grandTotal[0] + grandTotal[1])}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View>
                <Button style={styles.checkoutButton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Checkout")}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>CHECKOUT</Text></Button>
            </View>
        </View>

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Found Somewhat of an answer of what is causing this issue. Issue is with the ₹ symbol and if i remove it. It shows up. Will keep updated on how to make it work with the Symbol

Edit1: So the JSX as a string does not update realtime somehow as i am using redux value to convert it to comma type price and then add Rupee symbol separately with space. Removing it renders real time and has no issues. Somehow redux state value converted to string does not work.